# How much will future employers enquire about my past?

Tags: termination

I was fired from a trading firm for an inappropriate blog that I had. I have a noncompete for a year. Will future firms inquire about the reason I was let go from my last job? Will this affect me down the road? The blog is taken down now btw. My company is based in Chicago but I work in Amsterdam.

I work as a quant trader. If anyone knows about this field specifically it would be really helpful.

The blog included posts I made about other coworkers and my boss. Some of them fell under the 'racist, sexist, homophobic' category.

I just want to know if this will follow me down the line. Does the company I was fired from have an obligation to tell a future employer?

Comment: *I have a noncompete for a year* That only matters if it is enforceable. Stating your location will also help getting a more useful answer.

Comment: What is a "competitive trading firm" ?    To be totally honest, if you "work as a 'quant trader'" it is somewhat strange you would be asking a question at this level.

Comment: @Joe Strazzere, I'd like to have some honest questions : When you ask the reason some employees were separated from their old companies, do those old companies always tell you the reasons ? If yes, do they tell you the specific reasons ? For example, if the workers were fired, do the companies tell you that the workers violate which policy and in which way ? What is the percentage of the companies that give you the detailed reasons ? and What is the percentage of the companies that refuse to give any reason ? (I am just curious.) Thanks

Comment: Can they find the blog by Google searching your name?

Comment: Joe makes a good point. Remove your blog from the wayback machine. Change the robots.txt or the sitemap.xml. The wayback machine honors robots.txt. At the same time, start another blog, one that is non-political and have professional friends proofread it before you publish it. I know this doesn't answer your question, but I just thought I'd contribute my 2 cents where I could.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Thanks for the suggestion! Yeah I think i should create a new blog

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Yes I've apologized but it didn't really make much of a difference. This might be a stupid question but do employers actually google your name? Because I'm pretty sure that for my last job, they only did a background check and since that came out clean, I was hired.

Comment: @user477465, Officially, no one googles your name (because they could learn of a disability or of something that they're not supposed to know about). But unofficially, if your name is unique enough, you should assume that they're going to google it. All it takes is just one of your future co-workers to google you.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk: The question mentions Amsterdam, and therefore the GDPR applies. That's a bit stricter than typical US practice - everything is protected by default, not just disabilities.

Comment: @Abigail: Since it's now clear that it's Amsterdam, the non-compete would be enforceable by default. But typically in the required lawsuit the employee can make a counter-claim to revoke it. And if it's an out-of-court settlement, that's even easier.

Answer (score 1):

You say you work in Amsterdam, and I'll assume it the a corporate office in Amsterdam not a remote position. The company then needs to follow the Dutch law. There is precedent here that a former employer is NOT allowed to share information about you without your explicit consent.

Employers are obligated to deliver (on your request) a testimonial that includes start/end dates, hours worked per week and the sort of work you did. With your permission, they are allowed to include the way you left the company (fired or because you resigned) and the reason why if you were fired. But that is up to you, and the standard testimonial will not have the information about the reason you were fired.

If you do not give permission, your former employer is not allowed to share anything.

Sources: [1](https://www.jpr.nl/actueel/nieuws/informatie-delen-met-nieuwe-werkgever-van-ex-werknemer-mag-dat), [2](https://www.judex.nl/rechtsgebied/werk-ontslag/solliciteren/artikelen/mag-een-kandidaat-werkgever-referenties-over-mij-inwinnen/)  both in Dutch.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, the previous company will only tell the background check team hired by the new company that you worked for your old company from this month/year to that month/year. That is the most common info disclosed by the old companies.

Usually, the old company will not tell the new company the reason you no longer worked at the old company (for many reasons). They will not disclose your salary info at the old company either.

---

This message is from the general experiences with US companies located in the US.

(As of now, I don't know the location of the OP from his/her question yet).

Comment: Competitive (day) trading is a high risk high reward industry, it’s also probably a extremely niche community, which means a background check likely will be more involved than most.  Competition might be willing to overlook the inappropriate blog, since that’s a subjective decision, and corrective actions have already taken place.  The noncompete is another story, enforcement of the noncompete, takes time and money only the author knows if their previous employer would be willing to go to the hassle of enforcing it.

Comment: why would anyone vote this down?

Comment: Donald, I still don't know what "competitive! day! trading!" means, but it's no different at all from any other company that has a legal staff.  They will state: the day you start and the day you left. End Of Story.

Comment: @Fattie, Thanks for asking a good question.   :-)    BTW, I also notice that some people also randomly downvote some of your answers without giving any explanations. :-)

Comment: @JoeStrazzere interesting. i added some more details about my case. do you think  that specifically a trading firm will communicate the reasons I was fired?